# Looking for a library for parsing and extracting objects from ppt, pptx, doc, docx files

Tags: java, powerpoint, openoffice.org, docx, doc

I am looking for a library that can open a ppt, pptx, doc, docx files parse it and extract all objects from it.

for example, in ppt it can extract all object properties like images, text, tables autoshapes etc.. then provide me with object location/size and formatting like font size/color/bold etc.. and for images the ability to save each image to a jpg file.
The library should also be able to take a snapshot of the whole slide.

I have tried [aspose](http://www.aspose.com/) for doing this, but it wasn't accurate in getting this information. doesn't extract all properties plus it's export as image isn't accurate. Is there any ideas in using open office library for doing that?

I am open to use Java or a C++ library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At work we used the openoffice Java api to extract the images from ppt/pptx files. I used the docs from [here](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/OpenOffice.org_Developers_Guide). I am pretty sure you can use the info in that guide to do what you need.

good luck.

Comment: thanks alot craftand for your help
can you point out a simple example to extract images from a ppt/pptx file, I need to compare the extracted images with that ones i got from aspose to make a decision of switching to open office
thanks in advance

Comment: You can use Apache Tika as complete solution. Another good library is  [RawText](https://rawtext.ambar.cloud/), as it can do an OCR over images. It's non-free, and it works over REST API.

Answer (score 1):

One option is the [apache poi](http://poi.apache.org/) library - there's examples around and there seems to be more material around than on the openoffice API.